Find substring of digits in given string
Can not understand how parts of code works. The code should finde all digits and create int or float value, if "-" before first digit in given string, value should be with "-" sign. If there there is dot between digits in given string, first dot shoud be used to create float value, other dots are ignored.
def reveal_num(line: str):
    
    res = sign = ""
    dot = False
    
    for char in line:
        if char in "+-" and not res:
            sign = "-"*(char == "-")
        elif char in "." and not dot:
            dot = True
            res += "."
        elif char.isdigit():
            res += char
        
    if res:
        return(int, float)[dot](sign + res)

print(reveal_num("-aB%|_-+-2ADS.12+3.ADS1.2"))

Can not understand line.   What *(char == "-") does?
sign = "-"*(char == "-")

Can not understand line.
return(int, float)[dot](sign + res)

Could you please explain those lines

Depending on what you are really trying to do, the logic may be wrong. In your specific example you get the right answer, but if we get rid of the first minus your result will be wrong. This is evidenced by the fact that eval('--+-2) is -2, but eval('-+-2') is 2. However, your example will begin with -2 even if we remove the first minus.

more... you could save all of the + and - up to the first digit then only look for digits and the first dot. Once you have all of those parts, replace the int and float casts with eval. The reason this matters is because you are actually completely ignoring the +, but + before the first digit has meaning.

This is deliberate obfuscation and is about as far removed from the Zen of Python as you can get. It's also broken due to inappropriate use of str.isdigit

Who wrote that? That seems to be writtien as confusing as possible on purpose...
sign = "-"*(char == "-") is just a very obscure way of writing:
if char == "-":
    sign = "-"

Explanation: boolean b = (char == "-") will evaluate to b = 0 (False) or b = 1 (True) in this context so that "-"*b will be either "" (in this case no need to redefine since sign is already the empty string) or "-"
In the same way, return (int, float)[dot](sign + res) is a very obscure way of writing:
if dot:
    return float(sign + res)
else:
    return int(sign + res)

Explanation:
(int, float) creates a tuple. boolean dot will again evaluate as an integer in this context to grab the 0th (False) or 1st (True) element of that tuple, which is a string to number conversion function in either case, to finally apply it to sign + res
